# Inequality proof by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I've been wrestling with the following inequality for 3 days to prove it by CSI, but I can't choose the right column vectors $u$ and $v$ of CSI.

$$
\frac{a^2_1}{b_1}+\frac{a^2_2}{b_2}+\cdots+\frac{a^2_n}{b_n}\ge\frac{\left(a_1+\cdots+a_n\right)^2}{b_1+\cdots+b_n}
$$

How on earth should I fix these vectors?

Comment: Are you sure CSI is applicable to solve this one?!

Comment: @Roboticist: Not really. Although, I've already proved some similar inequalities using CSI. and I think it is solvable by that.

Comment: I'm guessing the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are all positive real numbers?

Comment: @carmichael561: Yes, definitely.

Comment: Remark: On the Art of Problem Solving (AoPS) we called this Titu's Lemma. It was the form of CS I tend to use.

Comment: This is called Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in Engel's form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since all the $b_i>0$, it follows from Cauchy-Schwarz that
$$ \Big(\sum_ia_i\Big)^2=\Big(\sum_i\frac{a_i}{\sqrt{b_i}}\sqrt{b_i}\Big)^2\leq\Big(\sum_i\frac{a_i^2}{b_i}\Big)\Big(\sum_ib_i\Big)$$ 
which yields the desired inequality.

Comment: Mathematics is damn TRICKY!

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: write $a_i = \dfrac{a_i}{\sqrt{b_i}}\cdot \sqrt{b_i}$ for each $i$.

Answer (score 2):

As a separate answer from the one I just posted. This time put $x_i = \dfrac{a_i}{b_i}> 0$, and asume: $a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_n = 1 = b_1+b_2+\cdots + b_n$, then we prove: $b_1x_1^2+b_2x_2^2+\cdots + b_nx_n^2\ge 1$. The function $f(x) = x^2$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$, thus Jensen inequality gives: $b_1f(x_1)+b_2f(x_2)+\cdots + b_nf(x_n) \ge f(b_1x_1+b_2x_2+\cdots + b_nx_n)$ translates into $b_1x_1^2+b_2x_2^2+\cdots +b_nx_n^2 \ge f(1) = 1$. 
Done !

Comment: Isn't the applied assumption a little bit restrictive, though? I mean, what if the summations do not equal 1?

Comment: You can assume both sums equal to $1$. Can you figure out why ?